# rspec have_link doesn't match action-mailer view when Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, actionmailer, rails-i18n

I'm having trouble using rspec's `have_link` on localized emails encoded as `quoted-printable`

From the rails console with `I18.locale = :en`

```
UserMailer.signup_confirmation(User.last.decorate).parts[1].encoded
```

yields

```
"Content-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n<p>Hello,</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Thank you for registering!</p>\r\n\r\n<p><a href=\"http://example.com/en/users/119/edit\">Edit profile</a></p>"
```

whereas `I18.locale = :es` yields

```
"Content-Type: text/html;\r\n charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\r\n\r\n<p>=C2=A1Hola,</p>\r\n\r\n<p>Thank you for registering!</p>\r\n\r\n<p><a href=3D\"http://example.com/es/users/119/edit\">Editar perfil</a></=\r\np>=\r\n"
```

notice the differences in the links

```
:en - <a href=\"http     # Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
:es - <a href=3D\"http   # Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

when I test these in `rspec` using

```
expect(msg).to have_link(translated_name, href: localized_url)
```

it passes for `:en` but fails for `:es`.

How should I test for the existence of a link on an html email view when it is `quoted-printable`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue rspec and links. The fault isn't really with rspec. It's the old case of garbage in, garbage out. Get the unencoded version of the html part and pass *that* into your expectation:

```
expect(msg.html_part.decoded).to have_link(translated_name, href: localized_url)
```